# Typescript enforce function argument is instance of class

Tags: typescript

What should I do to declare a function that take a class instance as argument

```
class Message{
    constructor(readonly text:string){}
}



function publish(message:Message){
    if(!message instanceof Message){
        throw new Error("arg message is not instance of Message")
    }
    ...
}
```

I would NOT expect the following code to compile

```
publish({text:"HELLO!"})
```

but it compiles and for sure the object passed to the function has the same properties but it is not an instance of Message.
I would like to enforce the argument to be an insance of that class.

Comment: You can use something like `private _o: any;` - additional property which ensures that `{text:"HELLO!"}` would not pass.

Comment: Note that this structural property of TS is extremely useful for writing unit tests so I'd rethink whether you really want to force this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript uses type signatures to decide if it can compile. Your code will compile because the object of `{text: "HELLO"}` matches the signature of the `Message` class.

If you have something calling the `publish` function after compile, you'll still need to perform the `if(message instanceof Message === false)` and throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily add private property in the class, then if someone tried to pass plain object will face error `TS2345`

e.g.

```
class Message {
    private readonly _type = 'Message';

    constructor(readonly text:string){}
}
```

I prefer to make the private property _type, but you can name it something like `private _enforce_instance = ''`